# Should PTR for domain controller be automatically created?

Tags: windows-server-2016, ptr-record

Reverse look up for my domain controller doesn't work.

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -VMName $vmname  -ScriptBlock {Install-WindowsFeature DNS -IncludeManagementTools}
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -VMName $vmname -ScriptBlock {Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name gj2corp.com -ZoneFile 'gj2corp.com.dns'}
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -VMName $vmname -ScriptBlock {Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -NetworkID 192.168.64.0/24 -ZoneFile '64.168.192.in-addr.arpa.dns'}
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -VMName $vmname -ScriptBlock {Add-DnsServerForwarder -IPAddress 8.8.8.8 -PassThru}
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -VMName $vmname -ScriptBlock {Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name gj2corp.com -DynamicUpdate 'NonsecureAndSecure' -PassThru}
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -VMName $vmname -ScriptBlock {Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name '64.168.192.in-addr.arpa' -DynamicUpdate 'NonsecureAndSecure' -PassThru}
```

If I manually add a PTR record for it, then it works. Should I have to add it manually?

Tried it on Windows 2016 and 2019

Comment: I realize your DC is most likely not using DHCP, but check out some of the solutions in this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/639398/reverse-dns-records-not-registered-when-using-dhcp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have AD, DNS and DHCP all in one as it is a test VM. I'll try "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration in a bit."